# How many sub-sums of the harmonic series converge to a given $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cardinals

Pick some positive $x$. $\hspace{0.5mm}$ Let $\mathcal{C}_x$ be the set of all subsets $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $\displaystyle{\hspace{1mm} \sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n} = x}$.

Is $\mathcal{C}_x$ countable?

(There are follow-ups and generalizations of this question one might ask, too, which I omit here to keep it neat. $\hspace{0.5mm}$ However, answers to more general versions of this question are welcome.)

Comment: The generalization that comes to mind is replacing the harmonic series with an arbitrary divergent series with positive decreasing terms tending to zero. Also we could consider the possible order types of ${\cal C}_x$ if it inherits the lexicographic ordering (i.e. $S_1<S_2$ if $\min(S_1\triangle S_2)\in S_1$).

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathcal C_x$ must be uncountable.

For any $x>0$ and $S\in\mathcal C_x,$ we set $S_*=\{1/n;~n\in S\}$ and $$I_x=\{S_*;~\hbox{$S$ is an infinite set}\}.$$ Then, $I_x\neq\emptyset,$ and $I_x$ is indeed an infinite set. For convenience, we may assume that each element of $I_x$ is a decreasing sequence. We are going to show that $I_x$ is a perfect set in the Banach space $l^1$.

- $I_x\subset l^1$ is a closed subset. For any $n\in\mathbf N_+$ and $A_n=(a_{n,1},a_{n,2},\ldots)\in I_x$ with $$\sum_{k\geq1}a_{n,k}=x,$$ we suppose that $\{A_n\}$ converges to $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ in $l^1.$ Then, $$\sum_{k\geq1}|a_{n,k}-a_k|\to0\quad\hbox{as $n\to\infty,$}$$ which implies that $$\sum_{k\geq1}a_k=x,$$ so we suffice to show that $a_k>0$ for every $k\in\mathbf N_+.$ By convention, we deduce that $a$ is a decreasing sequence. Suppose $j$ is the least index such that $a_j=0.$ Then, $a_i>0$ for any $1\leq i\leq j-1$, and $a_i=0$ for any $i\geq j.$ Since $$a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,i},$$ and we note that $$a_{n,i}\in\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\},$$ and $0$ is the unique limit point of $\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}.$ We then obtain that $a_i=a_{n,i}$ for $1\leq i\leq j-1$ and some large $n.$ Thus, $$\sum_{1\leq i\leq j-1}a_{n,i}=x,$$ which is a contradiction as $A_n$ is an infinite set. By the same reason, we get that $a$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. Hence, $a\in I_x$.
- $I_x$ has no isolated point, which is because that each element of $I_x$ is an infinite set. The proof is not difficult but lengthy, and so we omit the details.

Comment: Above argument is still valid for a general case that $\sum_k x_k$ is a divergent positive series, and $\{x_k\}$ is strictly decreasing to $0$.

Comment: +1. A non-empty complete metric space has a subset homeomorphic to the Cantor set. So $C_x$ has the cardinal of the reals.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for the comment, but your statement might be not true. For example, we consider the set $\{1/n;~n\in\mathbf N_+\}$ with the usual metric, it is complete in the sense of Cauchy, but it is countable.

Comment: I left something out. What I meant was a non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points has a subset homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of non-negative reals such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}a_n=\infty.$

Let $x>0.$

We can find disjoint $A_1,B_1\subset \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{j\in A_1}a_j=x/2=\sum_{j\in B_1}a_j.$

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ we can find disjoint $A_{n+1}, B_{n+1}\subset\Bbb N$ such that $A_{n+1}\cap (\cup_{j\le n}(A_j\cup B_j))=\emptyset =B_{n+1}\cap (\cup_{j\le n}(A_j\cup B_j))$ and such that $\sum_{j\in A_{n+1}}a_j=x2^{-n-1}=\sum_{j\in B_{n+1}}a_j.$

Now for $ f:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ let $f^*(n)=A_n$ if $f(n)=0,$ or $f^*(n)=B_n$ if $f(n)=1.$ And let $\psi (f)=
\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}f^*(n).$ Then $$\sum_{n\in\psi(f)}a_n=x.$$

If $f:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ and $g:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$ with $f\ne g$ then $\psi(f)\ne \psi (g).$

Comment: @Rurifangtun. Thank you. My proofs are instead usually the longest & most complicated.